# How to perform logical test on vector names within an apply function in R

Tags: r, apply, names

I'm using an apply function to scrape several web pages from the stat.NCAA.org site, with the goal of joining all the data into a single tibble. I am trying to clean the data within the apply function so I can avoid assigning variable names to the data scraped from each web page, which would slow down the process (this is for a project that will eventually scrape a few thousand pages).

Within my apply function, I need to perform a logical test on the name of the url accessed, to know which cleaning functions to apply for that specific data, but I do not know how to access names within a function. Here's my working code:

```
#Load Libraries
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

#Define URLs for stat tables (URL order must be in the order of the vector of names in row 22)
Wartburg_2018_url_vector <- c('https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14355',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14349',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14350',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14353',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14357',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14348',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14341',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14352',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14351',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14342',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14340',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14346',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14345',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14347',
                              'https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/stats?game_sport_year_ctl_id=14280&id=14280&year_stat_category_id=14356')
names(Wartburg_2018_url_vector) <- c('Defense',
                                     'Fumbles',
                                     'Kicking',
                                     'Kickoffs and KO Returns',
                                     'Participation',
                                     'Passes Defended',
                                     'Passing',
                                     'Punt Returns',
                                     'Punting',
                                     'Receiving',
                                     'Rushing',
                                     'Sacks',
                                     'Scoring',
                                     'Tackles',
                                     'Turnover Margin')

#launch RSelenium
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

#access webpage, parse the html, read the table/list, select the stat grid, convert to data frame, 
#convert to tibble, convert player names to character string, and name list elements
Wartburg_2018_stat_grid <- Wartburg_2018_url_vector %>%
  lapply(
    function(x) {
      remDr$navigate(x)
      htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>%
        readHTMLTable(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
        (function(y) {
          y[3]
        }) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        as_tibble() %>%
        mutate(Player = stat_grid.Player) %>%
        if(names(x) == 'Defense') {
          mutate(FR = as.double(gsub(",","",stat_grid.Fumbles.Recovered)),
                 Blocks = as.double(gsub(",","",stat_grid.Blkd))
          ) %>%
            select(Player:Blocks)
        }
    }
  )
```

I get the following error:

> Error in if (.) names(x) == "Defense" else { :    argument is not
>   interpretable as logical

When I try to run a simple apply function where I need to access the names within the function, my issue appears to be that `names(x)` returns a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the list identifier with `names()`

When using `lapply()`, you are converting `Wartburg_2018_stat_grid` to a list, then running the functions you specify.
Similarly, you could do:

```
myList <- as.list(Wartburg_2018_stat_grid)
myList
```

You can retrieve a value from the list by using it's identifier. e.g.

```
myList$Defense
```

This returns the item stored under that identifier. This is different from the name of that item.

The name is not specified. hence:

```
names(myList$Defense)

NULL
```

You could specify a name using:

```
names(myList$Defense) <- 'name1'
myList$Defense

                                          name1
"https://stats.ncaa.org/team/750/(...)id=14355"
```

This will add a name to the item in your list `myList` that is found under the identifier `Defense`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense why names(x) returns a NULL value, but I'm still unclear how I would perform a logical test on a list identifier instead.

Comment: Would if perhaps be more appropriate to use a different apply function--one that does not coerce my vector of URLs into a list?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your example (can't connect to remote server). You could try making a data.frame with the urls in one column and the names in another.  `df <- data.frame(url=c('url1','url2',...), statistic=c('Defence','Fumbles',...)).` If you use `apply(df, 1, function(x) { ... })` you might be able to do it. The `1` in `apply()` means running the function for each row of you dataframe. The names are inherited by `x` in `function(x)`. e.g. `x['url']` or `x['statistic']`

Comment: That worked! I had to rearrange the order of my functions a bit, too, with the if statement before I define my piped functions, but it's doing what I want it to do.